# How to change a dictionary while iterating over its keys while iterating over a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, iteration

1. I have a list l.
2. I have a dictionary d.

I want to iterate over l. For any list-item, I want to iterate over the d.keys.

If some condition is met, I would like to 'update' my dictionary.

I have naively tried to nest two for-loops and put in an if-statement -- One cannot change the length of the object one is iterating over.

```
d = {'this': '1', 'is': '2', 'a': '3', 'list': '4'}

l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

for word in l:
    for key in d.keys():
        if len(key) < 2:#some condition
            d.pop(key)
        else:
            print(word, key)
```

This is the output I get:

```
A this
A is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled3.py", line 6, in <module>
    for key in d.keys():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: I think the way to go should be to build a new dictionary with the keys, that do not match the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not change the size of a dictionary while iterating over a view of that dictionary. You can, instead, construct a new dictionary and *then* print whatever you like. For example:

```
d = {'this': '1', 'is': '2', 'a': '3', 'list': '4'}
L = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

d_new = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(k) >= 2}

for word in L:
    for key in d_new:
        print(word, key)
```

As described in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

> The objects returned by `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and
>   `dict.items()` are view objects. They provide a dynamic view on the
>   dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes,
>   the view reflects these changes....
>   **Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may
>   raise a RuntimeError or fail to iterate over all entries.**

Answer (score 4):

Instead of looping over `d` you could loop over a copy.

```
d = {'this': '1', 'is': '2', 'a': '3', 'list': '4'}

l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

for word in l:
    for key in d.copy().keys(): # Notice the change
        if len(key) < 2:#some condition
            d.pop(key)
        else:
            print(word, key)
```

Comment: Copying the whole dictionary `len(l)` times might be a little expensive. Also to iterate over a dictionary's keys you can just use `for key in d.copy():`, no need to access `keys()`.